# How to make a keymap within a list of a variable

Tags: emacs, elisp

Could anyone give me some assistance, please, to `make-sparse-keymap` within the following example and create at least one sample entry within that new keymap.

I'd like to create sub-menus to better organize and add additional entries to those sub-menus.  This example is borrowed from the function `menu-bar-update-buffers` within `menu-bar.el`, and I have adapted a modification of the function to work with a right-click `pop-up` context menu.

```
(setq lawlist-context-menu-command-entries
  (list
    '(command-separator "--")
    (list
      'next-buffer
      'menu-item
      "Next Buffer"
      'next-buffer
      :help "Switch to the \"next\" buffer in a cyclic order")
    (list
      'previous-buffer
      'menu-item
      "Previous Buffer"
      'previous-buffer
      :help "Switch to the \"previous\" buffer in a cyclic order")
    (list
      'select-named-buffer
      'menu-item
      "Select Named Buffer..."
      'switch-to-buffer
      :help "Prompt for a buffer name, and select that buffer in the current window")
    (list
      'list-all-buffers
      'menu-item
      "List All Buffers"
      'list-buffers
      :help "Pop up a window listing all Emacs buffers") ))
```

---

**EDIT**:  Issue resolved --  I modified the example for creating the `Frames` menu folder as was done within `menu-bar-update-buffers` from `menu-bar.el`. See answer below.

Comment: Does OneKey at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OneKey can help for the purpose? Perhaps you can integrate your requirement with OneKey.

Comment: @aartist  Thank you for the suggestion and link -- greatly appreciated.  My goal was to create a custom right-click context menu that displays all open buffers and frames (if they exist), *and* include some handy links to useful functions that are organized into submenu.  I had previously incorporated the major-mode menu, and the YASnippet menu of available snippets.  The context menu is now working -- here is a link on Github if anyone is interested:  https://github.com/lawlist/emacs-mouse-pop-up-context-menu/blob/master/context-menu.el  The buffer menu list includes up to 20 and hidden ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the example for creating the `Frames` menu folder as was done within `menu-bar-update-buffers` from `menu-bar.el`.  Issue resolved.  Instead of using `make-sparse-keymap`, just `keymap` is used instead.

```
(setq lawlist-context-menu-command-entries `(
  (test-one-separator "--")
    (test-one-folder-heading menu-item "TEST" ,(cons 'keymap (list
      (list
        'next-buffer
        'menu-item
        "Next Buffer"
        'next-buffer
        :help "Switch to the \"next\" buffer in a cyclic order")
      (list
        'previous-buffer
        'menu-item
        "Previous Buffer"
        'previous-buffer
        :help "Switch to the \"previous\" buffer in a cyclic order")
     '(test-two-separator "--")
      (list
        'select-named-buffer
        'menu-item
        "Select Named Buffer..."
        'switch-to-buffer
        :help "Prompt for a buffer name, and select that buffer in the current window")
      (list
        'list-all-buffers
        'menu-item
        "List All Buffers"
        'list-buffers
        :help "Pop up a window listing all Emacs buffers"))))))
```